# Scaffold-DbContext naming convention ignores [Key] attribute. How to stop it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

In EF Core *"Database first"* scenario, it is recommended to use `Scaffold-DbContext` to reverse engineer db schema to C# model classes. I've tried that and saw that when primary key matches naming convention that EFCore is using, they attribute is NOT generated. Examples:

**Example1:**

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    weirdId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,

);
```

will be converted into this class:

```
[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("weirdId")]
    public int WeirdId { get; set; }
}
```

**Example2: (hint: [Key] attribute is ignored**

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,

);
```

will be converted into this class:

```
[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is my thinking correct and this planned behavior? Will `Id` in the **Example 2** still be treated as Primary Key?
2. **How to stop it?** How to explicitly add primary key [Key] attribute? I'm pretty sure EFCore is doing the same for FK and God know what else. I like the naming conventions, but hate magic. I love consistency in the code, so if I have [Key] in one entity, I want it in all entities the same way. Please tell me there is a switch in Scaffold-DbContext to be more explicit?

EDIT:
I don't mean switching to `-DataAnnotations`. It still doesn't work. It still doesn't generate `Key` if the pattern (like in Example2) is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in EF Core 3.0, where Key will always be generated when using DataAnnotations https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/16682

Comment: Oh thasnk! This is what I was talking about. But.. I have the latest VS2019 but EFCore 3.0 is still not available. Should I install it manually? Is it safe/stable release?

Comment: It will be released next week!

Answer (score 0):

currently, I used with Oracl.EF, and it missing [Key] of the object.
but, It's very important. How can we should stop. My cmd:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "ConnectionString" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir OracleModels -DataAnnotations  -force;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `-d` when you are doing your scaffolding.

[image]

Comment: No. That only switches to DataAnnotation (I did that already). If the pattern meets naming convention, like I show in "Example 2", the `Key` attribute is still NOT generated.